# When file uploading private disk using laravel filament the download option not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I try to save my file uploads on a private disk, but I am unable to download my files after they have been uploaded.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CzRK.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8SyN.png)

in my filesystems.php

```php
'documents' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/documents'),
    'visibility' => 'private',
],
```

in my filament resource

```php
FileUpload::make('aadhar')
    ->disk('documents')
    ->directory('aadhar')
    ->visibility('private')
    ->maxSize(512)
    ->enableDownload()
    ->enableOpen()
    ->preserveFilenames()
```

Is there any way to download private disk files? I don't need files visible for public use.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a symlink for the private folder?

Comment: When I created symlink it attached with the public but I don't want public to see my files

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in Laravel.

```
Storage::get($filename);
```

You can also specify disk

```
Storage::disk('local')->get($filename);
```